# How to test outoing traffic on random ports? (I'm on OS X)

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port, network-traffic

In some situations or on some locations, I'm struggling with restricted **outgoing** traffic. For example a restricted LAN where outgoing traffic is only allowed on limited ports.

I know how to check or test my connection or network for *incoming* traffic on various ports. But I can't find how to do the opposite: checking on what ports I can make *outgoing* connections from my device.

Does anyone know how to do this? E.g. a way to probe a range of ports (regardless to what external server or IP).

I assume there are different ways to do this for different platforms: in this case I'm on OS X.

Note that I'm not dealing with a firewall or restriction on my own device, it's not a matter of local system configuration. I'm connected through a LAN which appears to have a very restrictive firewall or router or something, and I need to find out to which ports I can still connect to the outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nmap for this, by targeting `scanme.nmap.org` using a full range of ports.

```
nmap -Pn -p 1-65535 scanme.nmap.org
```

More on this topic here: https://hackertarget.com/egress-firewall-test/

Since you are on OSX you can get nmap here: https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html

Be aware however, that this practice may violate policies on the LAN you are connected to, so if you are concerned, contact an administrator before proceeding.

Comment: On an individual port basis, you can use telnet or netcat to test.